# Migrating to Team Foundation Server from Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I have been following the walk through here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181246(v=vs.90).aspx

But when it comes to the VSSConverter line, it's just not there. It's nowhere on my computer. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and none of the migration tools seem to be there. I have everything set up, including the TFS install and the VSS database. Where is this tool supposed to be?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you going to migrate to? The article you followed is migrating VSS to TFS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you followed is migrating VSS to TFS 2008, it's outdated. To migrate VSS to TFS 2013, you'll need [Visual SourceSafe upgrade tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/867f310a-db30-4228-bbad-7b9af0089282)s, which are a convenient method for a one-time, one-way upgrade of your codebase from Visual SourceSafe to Team Foundation Server (TFS).

After VSS data is prepared, upgrade from Visual SourceSafe using the wizard:
[image]

Refer to this article for detailed steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253060(v=vs.120).aspx